# DOM to XML transformer in mule is throwing exception

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing, mule

```
org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerMessagingException:
 javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: Maximum Number of Child Elements
 limit (50000) Exceeded (javax.xml.transform.TransformerException). 
Message payload is of type: 
 DepthXMLStreamReader (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerMessagingException). 
Message payload is of type: DepthXMLStreamReader
```

I am getting above exception while converting the payload from DOM to XML.

The payload I got from SAP, returns around 56 records.
How do I solve this exception?

Comment: So your xml does NOT contain >50000 elements?

Comment: it does!!  then I requested the SAP team to send me the payload in which it has less than nodes/elements.

Answer (score 0):

[This might help you. take a look at this](https://support.mulesoft.com/s/article/ka4340000004H3NAAU/Solve-javax-xml-stream-XMLStreamException-Maximum-Number-of-Child-Elements-limit-nnnnnn-Exceeded-err)